# how to evaluate this complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to evaluate $$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{(z-1)^3}dz.$$ At $z=1$, it has a pole of order $3$. I can not remember how to find the residue when there are poles with multiplicity, could any one tell me?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles

Comment: Do you know how to integrate by finding antiderivatives?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Na.

Answer (score 3):

Recall [Cauchy integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), which goes as follows. Let $f(z)$ be analytic inside an open set $\Omega$. Let $\Gamma$ be a closed curve inside $\Omega$. Let $z_0$ lie inside the closed curve $\Gamma$, we then have that
$$f^{(n)}(z_0) = \int_{\Gamma} \dfrac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}} dz$$
In your case, $f(z) = 1$, $n=2$, $z_0 = 1$ and $\Gamma$ is the circle $\vert z \vert = 2$. Hence, $f^{(2)}(z) = 0$. Hence, the integral is $0$.

Comment: Would it be $z_0\in\Gamma$?

Comment: @Kuttus Yes. The closed curve is $\Gamma$ and not $\Omega$. I have changed it.

Comment: @Kuttus: $\Gamma$ denotes the closed curve, not the region it bounds. Note that $z_0$ is in the interior of this region, so $z_0 \not\in \Gamma$.

Comment: will there be a $n!\over 2\pi i$ in the formula u have written? and I think something wrong with your answer

Comment: @TaxiDriver Yes. There should be $n!/(2 \pi i)$. But that won't change the fact that the answer is $0$.

Comment: do mean to say $f^{(2)}(1)=0$?, could you tell me why it is $0$?

Comment: because singularity at $z=1$ bothering me

Answer (score 2):

The residue is the coefficient $a_{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion $$\frac{1}{(z-1)^3}=\cdots+\frac{a_{-3}}{(z-1)^3}+\frac{a_{-2}}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{a_{-1}}{z-1}+a_0+a_1(z-1)+a_2(z-1)^2+\cdots.$$

Can you find a sequence $(a_n)$  making this equation hold?

Alternatively, the reason residues determine the integrals is that all terms of the form $a_n(z-a)^n$ with $n\neq -1$ have antiderivatives on $\mathbb C\setminus\{a\}$, hence integrate to $0$ on any closed curve not containing $a$.  In particular, the function you present has an antiderivative on $\mathbb C\setminus\{1\}$.